# Android gradle uploadArchives task issues on Jenkins

Tags: android, maven, jenkins, gradle, artifactory

I have a Jenkins job and one of the tasks executed is uploadArchives which should upload the generated .aar file to an Artifactory repo.

However I see this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

     What went wrong:
   Execution failed for task ':libmodule:uploadArchives'.
     Could not publish configuration 'archives'
        Error deploying artifact 'com.companyname:mylib:aar': Error deploying artifact: /var/empty/.m2/repository/com/companyname/mylib/1.0.0/mylib-1.0.0.aar (No such >file or directory)

    Try:
    Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Relevant parts of the build.gradle

```
repositories {
    maven{
        url 'http://artifacts.companyname.com/repository/android-shared-sandbox'
    }
}

def aarFile = file('build/libs/mylib.aar')
artifacts {
    archives aarFile
}

//Specify the URL and credentials to deploy the aar to the maven repository

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
          repository(url: "http://artifacts.companyname.com/repository/android-shared-sandbox"){
               authentication(userName: "username", password: "changeme")
            }
            pom.project {
               groupId 'com.companyname'
               artifactId 'mylib'
                packaging 'aar'
               version  '1.0.0'
            }
       }
  }
 }
```

This works from the command line on my laptop, also works on a local jenkins install on my laptop. I assume I am missing something simple here, but I cannot figure out why Jenkins is attempting to install it into some local maven repo instead of the on specified by the build.gradle task

Comment: Did you try running gradle with the `--info` or `--debug` options? They have helped me tracked down problems like this.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I am new to gradle, maven and only been a consumer of jenkins builds. I did look at the --info and --debug. As far as I can tell the build is looking in the wrong place for the .aar. The build seems to be looking for it in the /var/empty/.m2 directory instead of ../build/libs in the workspace.

Comment: Fixed by setting an environment variable in jenkins for M2_HOME!